# Liferay - get folder ID using folder name in velocity

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-velocity

I know how to get groupid in liferay velocity theme using:

```
#set ($scopeGroupId = $getterUtil.getLong($group_id))
```

However I also need to get a folder's ID using its name.
I have been researching for a while and don't seem to find a way to do that.

**Q:** Is this enabled and feasible in **liferay 6.2**?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are allowed to use `serviceLocator` or add in your portal-ext.properties this entry:

```
velocity.engine.restricted.variables=
```

After that you can use this code in your template:

```
#set ($folderLocalService =$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFolderLocalService"))
#set ($folderId = $folderLocalService.getFolder($groupId,0,"folder_name").getFolderId())

$folderId
```

Or you can use another method from `DLFolderLocalService`.

Comment: it is not working, it displays in browser $folderId . What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you add this property `velocity.engine.restricted.variables=`? Or maybe folder doesn't exist. Look at parameters in `getFolder`, second one is `parentFolderId` in above example.

Comment: yes I added the property, and the folder name I am using exists. It doesn't have a parentfolder, which means parentfolderid should be 0 correct?

Comment: Yes, 0 is default id for root folder. Which version of Liferay are you using? I've checked on `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5`.